# Getting content to scroll with the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my content to expand with the container div, but instead it gets cut off.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<section>
Lots of content goes here
</section>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer Content</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ECECEC;
  overflow: auto; 
}

#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  overflow: auto; /* Trying to make content scrollable */ 
}

.footer {
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;

}
```

The footer appears to overlap a portion of the content at the bottom. I have been searching around for answers and it seems that the positioning of the footer might be causing this problem. Is there a way to get the content to expand with the container div and continue to have the footer at the bottom in my case?

Comment: Posted the final answer after chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the CSS:

1. You should use `min-height: 100vh;` for `#container`. This says the height should be at least '100vh' and should grow taller if needed.
2. You should use `position: fixed;` for `.footer`. This will ensure the footer remains in the place regardless of the vertical scroll of the page.

Comment: Even with the changes, the footer still gets pushed up onto the contents.

Comment: @dtrinh100 I am sorry. You should set the 'overflow: scroll' on the parent. I will update the answer

Comment: This adds a scroll bar in the content section, but I just want the user to use the default browser scroll bar. Is there a way to do that? Also, some contents are still getting cut off.

Comment: @dtrinh100 Ok. I think I am getting your point. But there is one question for me. Why do you use ' position: absolute;' for the footer?

Comment: I'm using a solution that I found on here to keep the footer down at the bottom of the page, but it appears to have side effects.

Comment: @dtrinh100 Can you check this snippet and see if this is what you are looking for? If so I will add the explanation:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/musahaidari/z9bBX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90142/discussion-between-musa-and-dtrinh100).